# Using a printed table to find what fraction of a Gaussian population lies within various intervals

Tags: statistics

I'm having trouble understanding the question. The solution looks simple, but I do not understand the logic behind the problem. For example, (a). How is it that z=1 when z=(x - mu)/(sigma). [See problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAg5I.png)

[Normal table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOwgq.png)

Comment: A few things: please change your question title to something more meaningful, and do not just post image links to your question. It will also help to draw a picture.

Comment: No wonder you're puzzled. The question has flaws. Will try to help, please see my Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ have a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma.$
It is not possible to make printed distribution tables for all possible choices
of $\mu$ and $\sigma.$ So we transform $X$ to $Z$ with the 'standardization'
formula $Z = (X - \mu)/\sigma.$ If $X \sim \mathcal{Norm}(\mu = 100,\, \sigma=15)$ and you want $P(X \le 115),$ you write
$$P(X \le 115) = P\left(\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} \le \frac{115-100}{15} = 1\right) = P(Z \le 1) =  0.8413.$$ 
You can get $P(Z \le 1) = 0.8413$ from the printed standard normal table. In your
table, find the entry for 1.0 in the left margin, and read 0.3413--to which
you need to add 0.5000.

In the sketch below (following @SeanRobertson's suggestion), you want the area under the curve to the left of the
dotted red line. The total area under the curve is $1,$ half on either side
of the vertical green line. (Your table gives the area between the red and green lines.)

[image]

The answers to parts (a) and (b) are about 0.68 and about 0.95, respectively.
Parts (c), (d) and (e) are (let me see how to put this delicately) *total garbage* as written. That's one of the reasons
I'm trying to give you some help. (I guess that in (c) "$\mu$ to $\sigma$" was intended to mean
"between $\mu$ and $\mu + \sigma."$)